# MongoDB Update nested object of objects value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the format of:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af44cfbe2e96c58ec402efb"),
        "username" : "egealpay2",
        "email" : "egealpay2@gmail.com",
        "fullName" : "ege",
        "pnumber" : "",
        "oneSignal" : "d427dcdf-7939-4ada-a035-be74e1e45091",
        "friends" : [
                {
                        "email" : "baransrc@gmail.com",
                        "status" : 2
                }
        ],
        "alarms" : [
                {
                        "id" : "2",
                        "title" : "before",
                        "location" : "default",
                        "startTime" : "2018-05-16\t\t\t16:29",
                        "endTime" : "16:29\t\t\t17 - 05 - 2018",
                        "remindAt" : "17:29\t\t\t15 - 05 - 2018",
                        "privacy" : "0",
                        "userORJoinedAlarm" : "1",
                        "eventJoiners" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "ilkersadya@sabanciuniv.edu",
                                        "status" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "email" : "ilkercankayasss@sabanciuniv.edu",
                                        "status" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "email" : "ilkearcankaya@sabanciuniv.edu",
                                        "status" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "email" : "iaaalkercankaya@sabanciuniv.edu",
                                        "status" : 1
                                }
                        ],
                        "comments" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
```

i would like to set `status: 2` of `"email" : "ilkersadya@sabanciuniv.edu", its under`"alarms:" , "eventJoiners" :`which has an id of 2 as`"id"`

I have tried using push with $ but couldnt manage to get this working and its been bugging me over 2 hours.

Update i had tried thanks to @Ashish:

```
 dbo.collection("users").findOne( { email: userId } , function(errZer, addedZer) {
          dbo.collection("users").findOneAndUpdate( {email: addedID, "alarms.id": eventIDGiv,  alarms: { $elemMatch: { id: '2', eventJoiners: { $elemMatch: { email: addedID } } }} },
          { $set: { "alarms.$.eventJoiners.$.status": '2' } , function(err, added) {
```

got the error

```
(node:9334) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'alarms.$.eventJoiners.$.status'
```

Answer (score 3):

Positional operator (`$`) can be used only for one level of nested arrays. In your case you have to specify conditions both for `alarms` and `eventJoiners`. To do that you can use [$[< identifier >]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) syntax (which is available in MongoDB 3.6+):

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5af44cfbe2e96c58ec402efb") },
    { $set: { "alarms.$[elem1].eventJoiners.$[elem2].status": "2" } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem1.id": "2" }, { "elem2.email": "ilkersadya@sabanciuniv.edu" } ]})
```

In this case identifiers `elem1` and `elem2` are used as placeholders for conditions specifed in `arrayFilters` section.

Comment: im getting:  MongoError: cannot use the part (alarms of alarms.$[elem1].eventJoiners.$[elem2].status) to traverse the element ({alarms: [ { id: "3", title: "visi

Comment: please also note that im using node.js to make the call

Comment: @CompuScie which MongoDB version do you have ?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19

Comment: @CompuScie and are you able to upgrade ? I'm asking because as far as I'm concerned you can't update more than one level of nested arrays in versions below 3.6

Comment: i can update the mongo

Comment: so if i upgrade to 3.6 will this work?

Comment: @CompuScie yes it should, tested on my machine